# How do i make Autocomplete work with Appended fields?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, append, jquery-ui-autocomplete, materialize

I've been reading about this for days, i have not been able to figure this out... and i have already read A LOT ot questions just like mine, but it does not work in my code.

I have to know how many degrees have a person, so, HR asked me to use a lot of fields that many of them are required, i found somewhere an append function that allowed me to create more fields, and that works fine, in those fields there are two input text fields that use autocomplete (i am also using materialize library as a design framework) and they work just fine!, but when the input fields are generated they do not work and i've alreade changed them to a class and just don't work... so, here is the code.,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#insteducativa').autocomplete({
  source:"instedu.php",
 minLength:3,
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#progracademico').autocomplete({
 source:"progracademico.php",
minLength:3,
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields2      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper2         = $(".input_fields_wrap2"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button2      = $(".add_field_button2"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button2).click(function(a){ //on add input button click
    a.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields2){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper2).append('<div><div class="row" id="cumples"><div class="input-field col s2"><label for="modacademica" class="active">Modalidad Academica</label><select class="browser-default" id="modacademica" name="modacademica[]"><option value="" Selected disabled>--seleccione--</option><?php $resultado2 = mysql_query("SELECT idmodalidadacademica, modalidadacademica from modalidadacademica ORDER BY idmodalidadacademica"); while ($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2)) {echo "<option value=".$fila2["idmodalidadacademica"].">".utf8_encode($fila2["modalidadacademica"])."</option>";} ?></select></div><div class="input-field col s3"><input class="validate" type="text" class="insteducativa" name="insteducativa[]"><label for="insteducativa">Institución Educativa</label></div><div class="input-field col s3"><input class="validate" type="number" id="semaprobados" name="semaprobados[]" min="1" max="20"><label for="semaprobados">Semestres Aprobados</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><select class="browser-default" id="graduado" name="graduado[]"><option value="" disabled selected>--</option><option value="1">Si</option><option value="0">No</option></select><label class="active" for="graduado">Graduado</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn tooltipped red remove_field2"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a></div></div><div class="row"><div class="input-field col s6"><input class="validate" type="text" id="progracademico" name="progracademico[]"><label for="progracademico">Nombre Programa Academico</label></div><div class="input-field col s3"><input type="date" id="fechaterminacion" name="fechaterminacion[]"><label class="active" for="fechaterminacion">Fecha Terminación</label></div><div class="input-field col s3"><input type="text" class="validate" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}" id="numtarjprof" name="numtarjprof[]"><label for="numtarjprof"># Tarjeta Profesional</label></div></div></div><div>');
    }
  });    

  $(wrapper2).on("click",".remove_field2", function(a){ //user click on remove text
       a.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-content white">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">school</i>
          <span class="card-title center-align black-text text-black">Información Educativa Superior</span>
          <p>Ingrese su información de educación superior en <b>orden crónológico desde el más antiguo al más reciente</b>; si son cursos, diplomados etc. debe ingresar esta información en otro formulario.</p>
          <div class="input_fields_wrap2">
          <div class="row" id="cumples">
          <div class="input-field col s2">
                <label for="modacademica" class="active">Modalidad Academica</label>
                <select class="browser-default" id="modacademica" name="modacademica[]">
                  <option value="" Selected disabled>--seleccione--</option>
                    <?php
                      $resultado2 = mysql_query("SELECT idmodalidadacademica, modalidadacademica from modalidadacademica ORDER BY idmodalidadacademica");
                      while ($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
                        echo "<option value=".$fila2['idmodalidadacademica'].">".utf8_encode($fila2['modalidadacademica'])."</option>";
                      }
                    ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input class="validate" type="text" id="insteducativa" name="insteducativa[]">
                <label for="insteducativa">Institución Educativa</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input class="validate" type="number" id="semaprobados" name="semaprobados[]" min="1"
                max="20">
                <label for="semaprobados">Semestres Aprobados</label>
              </div>
            <div class="input-field col s2">
                <select class="browser-default" id="graduado" name="graduado[]">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>--</option>
                  <option value="1">Si</option>
                  <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
                <label class="active" for="graduado">Graduado</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s2">
               <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn tooltipped blue add_field_button2" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Añadir educacion superior"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input class="validate" type="text" id="progracademico" name="progracademico[]">
                <label for="progracademico">Nombre Programa Academico</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input type="date" id="fechaterminacion" name="fechaterminacion[]">
                <label class="active" for="fechaterminacion">Fecha Terminación</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input type="text" class="validate" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}" id="numtarjprof" name="numtarjprof[]">
                <label for="numtarjprof"># Tarjeta Profesional</label>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

HELP!... (i'll be around here)